# React PWA standalone feature is not working in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am having a PWA in ReactJs. My PWA works as standalone on localhost in IOS, but on real link, it opens with safari after login and is not standalone anymore. please help me.
All the internal links will open with safari and it is like as an external link.
my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "my name",
    "short_name": "my name",
    "description":"desc",
    "lang": "fa",
    "start_url": "/law",
    "scope": "/law",
    "display": "standalone",
    "id":"/law",
    "theme_color": "#34abc4",
    "background_color": "#34abc4",
    "icons": [
      {
          "src": "/law/Assets/Images/logo-package/icon-192x192.png",
          "sizes": "192x192",
          "type": "image/png",
          "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
          "src": "/law/Assets/Images/logo-package/icon-256x256.png",
          "sizes": "256x256",
          "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
          "src": "/law/Assets/Images/logo-package/icon-384x384.png",
          "sizes": "384x384",
          "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
          "src": "/law/Assets/Images/logo-package/icon-512x512.png",
          "sizes": "512x512",
          "type": "image/png",
          "purpose": "maskable"
      }
  ]
  }
```